# Insert default value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert records in a table with a column having same value for all the records being inserted.
How to do it **without changing table structure.**

```
Insert into tableA(clientid,no_of_users)
select clientid
from tableB
```

I want no-of_users =3 for all the records

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com). Particularly as this is [trivially easy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=default+sql+server) to Google.

Comment: ok , i will be be careful next time

Comment: Even though it's a simple question it's a valid one, agreed you should try harder to find the answer yourself, but I have no problem with questions like this. The world's changing why look for something when it's easier to ask and get from people who already know. @RB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [DEFAULT Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for this, read about it on MSDN.

Without changeing the table structure, just simple use this:

```
Insert into tableA(clientid,no_of_users)
select clientid, 3
from tableB
```

With using this statement, you can always think about the `INSERT` as the **output** what you would like to see of your `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In Sql server Modify your table. Select column name and set Default value for that column.

Comment: Thanks , will try this next time...